# vscode intellisense donnot work when union types have character and string type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

vscode intellisense doesn't work when union types have character and string type.

```
type t = 't1' | 't2';

var a: t = 't1';
```

```
type t = 't1' | 't2' | string;

var a: t = 't1';
```

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BheRk.jpg

Comment: In the second case type `t` is equivalent to `string` (literal types are absorbed by their supertype), so what did you expect from IntelliSense?

Comment: @Cerberus this issue actually has a decent workaround, It's not uncommon to allow any `string` but have a set of common strings you would like suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does simplifications on unions and intersections. One of these simplifications is base types absorb subtypes. `string` is the base type of all string literal types (such as `'t1'` and `'t2'`) This means as far as the compiler is concerned `type t = 't1' | 't2' | string;` is just a fancy way to write `string`.

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729) documents this exact problem and the proposed workaround should work for you as well:

```
type t = 't1' | 't2' | (string &  { fromT?: any});

var a: t = 'ty'; //ok
var a: t = 't2'; //ok, with autocomplete
```