# Why does VSCode typescript autocomplete behave so strangely on simple / complex union

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Basically I have a typescript type with 2 properties, and I expect VSCode to be able to autocomplete / intellisense the second of those properties after I complete the first.

The really strange thing is that VSCode can do this, but only if the union is complicated enough ... but not if it's very simple.

I think the easiest way to explain is with a couple of code examples.

This works the way you'd expect:

```
type MyGenericType<a, b> = {
  property1: a;
  property2: b;
};
type MyUnion =
MyGenericType<"a", "a">
| MyGenericType<"b", "b">
| MyGenericType<"c", "c">
| MyGenericType<"d", "d">
| MyGenericType<"e", "e">
| MyGenericType<"f", "f">
| MyGenericType<"g", "g">
| MyGenericType<"h", "h">
| MyGenericType<"i", "i">
| MyGenericType<"j", "j">;

const myConstant: MyUnion = {
  property1: "a",
  property2: "", // VSCode can suggest correctly the only possible string here is "a"
};
```

However, if we remove an item from the union things don't work:

```
type MyGenericType<a, b> = {
  property1: a;
  property2: b;
};
type MyUnion =
MyGenericType<"a", "a">
| MyGenericType<"b", "b">
| MyGenericType<"c", "c">
| MyGenericType<"d", "d">
| MyGenericType<"e", "e">
| MyGenericType<"f", "f">
| MyGenericType<"g", "g">
| MyGenericType<"h", "h">
| MyGenericType<"i", "i">;

const myConstant: MyUnion = {
  property1: "a",
  property2: "", // VSCode suggests property2 might be any letter from "a" to "i" (of course, it can only be "a")
};
```

To be clear, typescript (and VSCode) correctly identify when myConstant is constructed incorrectly. The issue is the autocomplete / intelisense.

If anyone has any idea what is going on here, or if it's a known bug ... or anything actually. That would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this appears to be a similar q&a: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628111/4676641 saying that VSCode does some simplifications when making suggestions for union/intersection types in TS. Also discussed in issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729.

Comment: Thanks for the comment tentative, really appreciate it. I'd agree it is similar, except that my example never refers to string as a type, and the difference in behaviour between having 9 and 10 items in the union.... so yeah the issue is similar "autocomplete" doesn't work ... but why does going from 9 to 10 items in the union get autocomplete to start working?